# Improperly concatenating LSTM layers in Python keras

Tags: numpy, keras, concatenation

I have two datasets with different temporal resolutions I want to input to the same LSTM model. I am running into issues with the concatenation process, even when I use a simple dataset, and believe I am missing something simple that I just cannot see. Let's take the following simple example which is a watered-down version of the method I am trying:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import layers

train_x1 = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,10,10)) # 10 samples, 10 time-steps, 10 variables
train_x2 = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,30,6)) # 10 samples, 30 time-steps, 6 variables

inp1 = layers.Input(shape=(train_x1.shape[1], train_x1.shape[2]))
inp2 = layers.Input(shape=(train_x2.shape[1], train_x2.shape[2]))

x = layers.LSTM(10)(inp1)
y = layers.LSTM(10)(inp2)

x = layers.Dense(1)(x)
y = layers.Dense(1)(y)

z = np.concatenate([x,y])
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

I am very confused where the error is stemming from in this example?

Comment: use the concatenate layer from keras layer... not np.concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `y` are keras tensor objects, it doesn't make sense to use `np.concatenate` on them. Probably you want to try `keras.layers.Concatenate()([x,y])`.